# combobox not showing default value even when set to dropdown list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, default

hi i have a combo box in a form which has the following values.cash sales,refund,debtor sales,debtor refund. i have added these values in the items collection.Following is the issue,the combo box during form load does not show the first value which is cash sales and which should be the default value displayed on form load.but its not showing.
I have even set the combo box style to drop down list but still its not showing.

```
   ![the combo box in form which has the mentioned issue][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to show the default value by index:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Update:
Or if you cant determine the index in design time, you can use:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf("defaultValue")
```